# Нахождение индексов одинаковых элементов в листе

Tags: c#, массивы, список

У меня есть лист со значениями, мне нужно составить алгоритм ,который находит индексы повторяющихся элементов. 
Допустим в этом примере он должен находить
(0 8)
(1 6).

[image: Лист со значениями]

неудачные попытки

```
public void SearchValues(Form1 form)
{
    var exploredList = WorkWithFiles.ExploreTable(form);
    var count = new List<int>();
    var count2 = new List<int>();
    var idx = new List<int>();



    for (var i = 0; i < form.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var l = exploredList[i].CountOfRoom;

        for (var j = 1; j < form.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2; j++)
        {
            if (l == exploredList[j].CountOfRoom)
            {
                count2.Add(j + 1);
                Console.WriteLine(j + 1);
            }
        }
    }














    for (var i = 0; i < form.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < form.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (exploredList[j].CountOfRoom.Equals(exploredList[i].CountOfRoom))
            {
                count.Add(i);
                count.Add(j);
                Console.WriteLine((i + 1) + "  " + (j + 1));
            }
        }
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < count.Count; i += 2)
    {
        if (count[i] == count[i + 1])
            count.RemoveRange(i, i + 1);

    }

    foreach (var VARIABLE in count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);
    }


    for (var i = 0; i < form.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (!count.Contains(exploredList[i].CountOfRoom))
        {
            count.Add(exploredList[i].CountOfRoom);

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < count.Count; j++)
        {
            if (count[i].Equals(count[j]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " " + j);
            }
        }
    }


    //foreach (var variable in count)
    //{

    //    for (var i = 0; i < form.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    //    {
    //        if (variable == exploredList[i].CountOfRoom)
    //        {
    //            count2.Add(i + 1);
    //            Console.WriteLine((i + 1));
    //        }
    //    }
    //}




    var jk = 0;
    List<int> func(int[] arr)
    {
        var li = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!li.Contains(arr[i]))
            {
                li.Add(arr[i]);

            }
            ++jk;
        }


        return li;
    }




















    foreach (var VARIABLE in count)
    {
        Console.Write((VARIABLE + 1) + " " + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: это ваше задание, но в чем ваш вопрос?

Comment: @tym32167 то есть ,я не могу составить алгоритм, у меня постоянно какая то каша получается. 
То у меня в список попадают 0 8   
 8 0 
 (итд), то ещё что-то. Просто я не знаю как составить алгоритм. Это не одно целое задание. Это очень маленькая часть большого.

Comment: в массиве только пара повторяющихся или может больше? 2, 2, 0, 2  - (0, 1, 3) или только 2, 0, 2 - (0, 1)

Comment: Можете показать ваши попытки? Ничего страшного, что ваш код не работает. Добавьте его в вопрос, расскажите, как вы пытались решить вашу задачу.

Comment: @AzizUmarov мне нужны все повторяющиеся элементы, не обязательно чтобы их было по 2 .

Comment: @tym32167 добавил

Comment: Что если переделать немного циклы? Первый `for (var i = 0; i < form.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)`, второй  `for (var j = i+1; j < form.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)`

Comment: @tym32167 можете пожалуйста написать конкретный вариант, просто суть в том что у меня там даже если они выбираются (индексы) тогда у меня к сожалению они потом повторяются

(0 8) 
(8 0)

и мне потом просто придется возиться с тем ,Чтобы убрать именно эти дубликаты

Comment: Можно бежать в цикле по списку, и пытаться добавлять текущий элемент в HashSet, у него метод Add() возвращает false если такой элемент уже есть в наборе, соответ. можно найти индексы повторяющихся элементов.

Comment: Если вы просто замените свои циклы моими циклами, то у вас не будет дубликатов. Вам надо только правильные строчки поправить.

Comment: @Bulson человек в 2 циклах плавает, хешсет он скорее не осилит, если вы ему код не напишете.

Comment: @Bulson можете пожалуйста предоставить пример? с HashSet никогда не работал

Comment: @tym32167 сейчас попробую , спасибо

Comment: @tym32167 В общем то получилось ,он выводит только 2 элементы которые повторяются.

к примеру 2 3 4 5 2 2 3 3 
он выводит индексы 4 5 6 7

Comment: Это хорошо, что получилось. У вас, по сути, осталась только 1 проблема - в ответе нет индекса первой двойки. Вы можете это сами порешить, нк или я вам добавил альтернативный ответ, который сворачивает оба ваших цикла в одну строчку.

Comment: @tym32167 буду пробовать ,спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете также использовать Linq, пример

```
var count2 = exploredList.Select((x, index)=>(x.CountOfRoom, index))
    .GroupBy(x=>x.CountOfRoom, x=>x.index)
    .SelectMany(x=>x)
    .ToList();

foreach (var index in count2)
    Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Comment: Ну, да это, конечно, проще чем с HashSet<int>. для начинающего то.

Comment: @Bulson так я ж сам код и написал. Я к тому, что с подсказок автор такое не осилит, а скопипастить много не надо знаний.

Comment: @Bulson я не против посмотреть и на ваш вариант!

Answer (score 0):

Пробегаете по массиву

```
for (int index = 0; index < list.Count; index ++) {   
   int currentIndex = index;
   do {
       currentIndex = list.IndexOf(list[index], currentIndex + 1);
       if (currentIndex > 0) {          
          Console.WriteLine($"Dublicate {list[index]} at ({index}, {currentIndex})");
       }
   } while (currentIndex == -1)
}
```

Comment: Там не массив, а `List<int>`